# Python: to_file, why am I not getting .prj file?

Tags: python

I would like to create GeoDataFrame from every row of my dataframe. Code works but I get .cpg, .dbf, .shp and .shx files. Why I don't get .prj file?

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    lokalnyid = row['lokalnyid']
    gdf = pd.DataFrame(row)
    gdf2 = gdf.transpose()
    gdf2 = gdf2[['lokalnyid', '1_5000_pi025', 'geometry', 'liczba_kon']]
    gdf2['geometry'] = gdf2['geometry'].map(shapely.wkt.loads)
    new_gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(gdf2, geometry= 'geometry')
    new_gdf['1_5000_pi025'] = ''.join(str(e) for e in new_gdf['1_5000_pi025'])
    new_gdf.to_file(f'/mnt/qnap/geo_tiff_roofs_testy22/{lokalnyid}.shp', encoding = 'cp1250')
```

Comment: Because you haven't set a [crs](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.crs.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.crs).

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: `gdf.crs = whatever your crs is`

Comment: works! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set a [crs](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.crs.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.crs).

```
gdf.crs = whatever your crs is
# e.g.
gdf.crs = 'EPSG:4326'
```